# Android Studio XML Requires Layout_Height and Layout_Width

Tags: android, xml

I found this code while searching for a button with good graphics,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:radius="100dp"
/>
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerColor="#7995A8"
android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
android:endColor="#000000"
android:type="linear"
/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```

However, when I copy and paste it into an XML file in Android Studio, it shows and error that says:

> "element shape does not have required attribute android:layout_height"

and another error:

> "element shape does not have required attribute android:layout_width"

I tried setting the `android:layout_width=""` and `android:layout_heigth""`
and `android:layout_width"wrap_content"`, `android:layout_heigth="wrap_content"`, the error is gone, but I can't set any button to have this as it's background ... so I can't use this XML this way.

What should I set them to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes for `<shape>`, because `<shape>` does not go in a layout resource, where you are trying to put it. A `<shape>` goes in a drawable resource, such as in `res/drawable/` in your project.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Drawable/Shape) demonstrates the use of `<shape>` drawable resources. You will see that the `<shape>` elements are in the `res/drawable/` directory.

You can also read more about `<shape>` drawable resources in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).

Comment: If you come to this page confused on how to do what CommonsWare describes using Android Studio, click on the dropdown over your file hierarchy on the left (that probably says Android or Project), and select Project. In this view you probably see the xml file giving you trouble in your layout folder instead of the drawables folder. Drag the file into drawable and the error will go away. Hope that helps